# Python Function App deployment to Azure fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, visual-studio-code

So I am trying to deploy my function app to Azure but I am getting this error.I couldn't find any info regarding this.I've been following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-vs-code and locally everything works fine. [image]

If I click to deploy anyway, then the message would be:
[image]

Thank you for any advice.

EDIT:
I was able to solve it by installing a desktop version of Docker

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wiki on the preview support for Python:

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Azure-Functions-on-Linux-Preview

If you deploy through VS Code and create a new function app - make sure to use one of these regions (copied from the doc above):
•   West US

•   East US

•   West Europe

•   East Asia

A list of known issues is available [here](https://github.com/search?q=org%3AAzure%20label%3Aplatform%3Alinux&state=open&type=Issues).

You can utilize CLI to deploy your python function app which you can do it in few steps pnly. Here is the link for the same.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python

Hope it helps.